# change() problems when blur() hides the field

Tags: jquery, onchange, blur

```
<input id="blur-test" type="text"/>

$('#blur-test').blur(function() { $(this).hide(); });
$('#blur-test').change(function () { alert('ok'); });
$('#blur-test').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) { $(this).blur(); }
});
```

When I change the field content and then unfocus it by mouse click everything is ok (alert appears). The problem occures when 'enter' is pressed. Blur event is triggered programmatically and the field hides but change() doesn't work. It hires only when I click somewhere on page or use tab. Looks like input hasn't lost focus. Why so? And how should I trigger blur correctly?

P.S. When the blur function body is empty it works fine.

Comment: Works just fine for me, the alert pops up and the field is hidden when hitting enter -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UaCv2/)

Comment: Well, you are right... thx. Maybe I should update jquery for my project. But on fiddle it works even with 1.6.4 version selected. Confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery update to 1.9.1 has fixed the problem. Cheers!